# .htaccess mod_rewrite domain to subdomain

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect any domain to a sub-domain. I know this has got to be possible but for the life of me i can not figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

For example:

`domain1.com`
`domain2.com`
`subdomain1.domain1.com`
`subdomain2.domain2.com`

all go to `subdomain3.domain.com`

but i need code that does not require me to enter each domain i want redirected. So for any feature domains that i link or create will go to subdomain3.domain.com btw this will only happen when viewing `anydomain.com/path` <-- the path is a sym link

Comment: In other words... if the domain is not "subdomain3.domain.com" then redirect to this?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if I understand your question right. If you want to redirect all requests to `path` to `subdomain3.example.com` just compare the hosts:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain3\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^path http://subdomain3.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

#### Update

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain3\.example\.com$
# At least one character after /
RewriteRule (.+) http://subdomain3.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ok so you really did not get it. I think. I just need any feature dome pointing to /path be redirected to the proper domain. so any domain coming into my site and pointing to /path will be redirected to subdomain3.mydomain.com/path

Comment: Should work now.

Comment: can you explain a little more on this. It does not work somewhat. It seems like it trys to work but does not fully redirect. the domain address still shows domain1.com/path domain2.com/path but the style sheet goes away i need a complete rewrite of any domain.

Comment: Then you have either later rewrite rules or your adaption is missing a critical part (maybe `R=301`?). What says your rewrite log?

Comment: wheres my rewrite log going to be

Comment: Depends on your hosting environment. Usually the same place where the regular logs are stored. Ask your hoster if you’re on a shared host.

Comment: i have a cloud server through rackspace. i control all of the logs. The rewrites and directorys are for bugzilla but the client has wordpress mu on there as well. They want only a certain subdomain access to bugzilla. so any other domains that are mapped or sites that are created do not have access to bugzilla through there domain name. Example *.domain.com does not have access to bugzilla directory just subdomain3.domain.com/bugzilla